# How to stop jQuery autocomplete from autosuggesting the full array in multiple values option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Using jQuery autocomplete multiple values option, how can I prevent autosuggestion for every new word.

The problem is that it shows the entire array when you press "space" which slow down (hang) some browsers when using a large array.

Increasing the `.minLength` value works for the first word, but once you press space it shows the entire array.

How do I stop it from doing that.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ru7i5kuOWzZ7CYu5KNxr?p=preview

```
  <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        function split( val ) {
          return val.split( / \s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
          return split( term ).pop();
        }

        $( "#tags" )
          // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
          .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          })
          .autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function( request, response ) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
      });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for empty string in request parameter in autocomplete source method like below

```
 if(request.term===' ')
          {
            response([{value: "Enter Some text to search"}]);
            return false;
          }
```

Take a look at this [jqfaq](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-prevent-suggestion-while-typing-white-space-in-autocomplete/) working sample which may helps you

Answer (score 0):

add this litte if-statement to your source-function

```
      if (extractLast( request.term ).replace(/ /g, "") == "") {
        return false;
      }
```

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0ruT3niV3UF0YMj5glZ?p=preview) as well.